# XSLT - calculate first and last position when grouping used to re-organise data

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to restructure an XML into 4 distinct 'blocks'. The final block must include a distinct value from a group-by and the position of the first and last instance within that group. As I am grouping the data to build the other blocks I cannot find a way to achieve this.

Original structure;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATASET>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AAA_007_-20</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1292UN-AAA_007_20 - IA3 Helicoils balancing masses</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0005</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204610</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>0</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>4636293</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>ORDEN DE DESPACHO. IA3 APLICABLE IAAA_007_20, CON REF. NRC MOS-NC-ASE-0074</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AAA_007_-20</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1292UN-AAA_007_20 - IA3 Helicoils balancing masses</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0010</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204610</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>0</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>4636294</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>DESPACHAR MATERIAL SEGUN ESTRUCTURA</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0010</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960079</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>DESMONTAJE CONJUNTO FEEDER IBERIA
===========================================================================
DESMONTAR CONJUNTO FEEDER IBERIA (AG100AE2526E.) Y ENVIAR A RYMSA.


...
VERIFICAR A-A</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0020</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960225</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>PREMONTAJE CONJUNTO BOCINA-POLARIZADOR
===========================================================================
UNIR CONJUNTO BOCINA POS.01 CON POLARIZADOR POS.02 MEDIANTE TORNILLOS
POS.08 Y ARANDELAS DE INVAR POS.10. S/SECCION E2-E2 DE</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0020</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960225</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>2</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>LA HOJA 01 DEL
PLANO. COORDINAR CARAS INTERNAS DE POLARIZADOR CON EJES DE BOCINA SEGÚN
NOTA 4.


...
VERIFICAR A-A.

===========================================================================
=    AVISAR A CONTROL DE PRODUCCION PARA ENVIAR</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0020</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960225</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>3</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>CONJUNTO A RF             =
===========================================================================</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0030</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960226</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>PRE-MONTAJE CONJUNTO BOCINA-SOPORTE BOCINA
===========================================================================
MONTAR SOPORTE FEEDER IBERIA POS.03 EN CONJUNTO BOCINA IBERIA POS.01 CON
TORNILLO POS.06 Y ARANDELA POS.07 S/SECCIÓN C1-C</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0030</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960226</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>2</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>1 Y E1-E1 DE LA HOJA 01 DEL
PLANO.


...
VERIFICAR A-A.

===========================================================================
=        AVISAR A CONTROL DE PRODUCCIÓN PARA ENVIAR CONJUNTO A RF         =
===============================</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0030</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960226</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>3</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>============================================</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960228</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>MONTAJE FINAL CONJUNTO FEEDER - PORALIZADOR
===========================================================================
MONTAR PASADORES POS.10 S/SECCIONES E1-E1 DE LAS HOJAS 01 DEL PLANO DESPUÉS
DEL AJUSTE DE RF S/NOTA 01 DE LA HOJA 01 DEL</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960228</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>2</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>PLANO.

PREPARAR MEZCLA DE ADHESIVO SOLITHANE S/IT-ERS-A005, APLICAR SOBRE ROSCA DE
LOS TORNILLOS POS.08 Y DAR DE APRIETE DEFINITIVO 2NM+PAR DE FRENADO SEGÚN
SECCIÓN TÍPICA DE LA HOJA 01 Y NOTAS 5 DEL PLANO.

PREPARAR MEZCLA DE ADHESIVO EC</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960228</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>3</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>2216 S/IT-S-A043, SELLAR TORNILLOS
POS.08 SEGÚN SECCIÓN TÍPICA Y NOTA  6 DE LA HOJA 01 DEL PLANO.

MONTAJE FINAL CONJUNTO FEEDER - SOPORTE FEEDER
===========================================================================
DAR DE APRIETE DEF</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960228</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>4</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>INITIVO A LOS TORNILLOS POS.06 DE 2,5NM+PAR DE FRENADO
SEGÚN NOTA DEL PLANO.


...
VERIFICAR A-A.</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0050</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0209835</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960229</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>CARACTERIZAR CONJUNTO FEEDER IBERIA
===========================================================================
VERIFICAR INTERFACES. RELLENAR REGISTRO DE INSPECCIÓN.


...
VERIFICAR A-A-X</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0060</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>4</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960230</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>PRE-MONTAJE FEEDER &amp; GUIA DE ONDA IBERIA
===========================================================================
REALIZAR OPERACIONES DESCRITAS EN EL APARTADO 6.4 DEL LIBRO DE MONTAJE.


PRE-MONTAJE FEEDER IBERIA
=======================</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0060</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>4</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960230</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>2</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>====================================================
REALIZAR OPERACIONES DESCRITAS EN EL APARTADO 6.8.2 DEL LIBRO DE MONTAJE.


MONTAJE FEEDER FINAL IBERIA
===========================================================================
REALIZA</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0060</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204810</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>4</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960230</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>3</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>R OPERACIONES DESCRITAS EN EL APARTADO 6.10.2 DEL LIBRO DE MONTAJE.


...
VERIFICAR A-A.</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0070</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0209835</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960232</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>ALINEAMIENTO FEEDER IBERIA
===========================================================================
ENGLOBA EL ALINEAMIENTO DEL FEEDER IBERIA. OPERACIÓN 6.9.2 DEL LIBRO DE
MONTAJE.


...
VERIFICAR A-A-X</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0080</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0209808</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>1</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960235</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>REALIZAR VERIFICACIÓN FINAL.

...
VERIFICAR A-A-G-X</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        <MATERIAL>AG1-ECE-NCR0-04</MATERIAL>
        <ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_DESCRIPTION>
        <OPERATION>0090</OPERATION>
        <WORKCENTRE>S0204610</WORKCENTRE>
        <OPR_CONTROLKEY>ZP01</OPR_CONTROLKEY>
        <OPR_DURATION>0</OPR_DURATION>
        <BAAN_TEXT_NBR>3960234</BAAN_TEXT_NBR>
        <BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>1</BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ>
        <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>ALMACENAR HASTA SU PRÓXIMO MONTAJE.</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
    </TABLE>
</DATASET>
```

XSLT so far;

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/DATASET">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="TABLE" group-by="ROUTING_DESCRIPTION">
      <BAPI>
        <ROUTING_ID>
          <xsl:value-of select="ROUTING_DESCRIPTION" />
        </ROUTING_ID>
        <OPERATIONS>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="OPERATION">
            <item>
              <xsl:copy-of select="OPERATION" />
            </item>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </OPERATIONS>
        <TEXT>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="concat(OPERATION, '|', BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ)">
            <item>
              <xsl:copy-of select="OPERATION" />
              <xsl:copy-of select="BAAN_TEXT_VAL" />
            </item>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </TEXT>
        <TEXT_ASSIGN>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="OPERATION">
            <item>
              <xsl:copy-of select="OPERATION" />
              <FROM></FROM>
              <TO></TO>
            </item>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </TEXT_ASSIGN>
      </BAPI>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my result;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BAPI>
    <ROUTING_ID>1292UN-AAA_007_20 - IA3 Helicoils balancing masses</ROUTING_ID>
    <OPERATIONS>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0005</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0010</OPERATION>
        </item>
    </OPERATIONS>
    <TEXT>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0005</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>ORDEN DE DESPACHO. IA3 APLICABLE IAAA_007_20, CON REF. NRC MOS-NC-ASE-0074</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0010</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>DESPACHAR MATERIAL SEGUN ESTRUCTURA</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
    </TEXT>
    <TEXT_ASSIGN>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0005</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0010</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
    </TEXT_ASSIGN>
</BAPI><BAPI>
    <ROUTING_ID>1707UN-AG1-ECE-NCR004 - REP. FEEDER IBERIA</ROUTING_ID>
    <OPERATIONS>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0010</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0020</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0030</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0050</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0060</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0070</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0080</OPERATION>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0090</OPERATION>
        </item>
    </OPERATIONS>
    <TEXT>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0010</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>DESMONTAJE CONJUNTO FEEDER IBERIA
    ===========================================================================
    DESMONTAR CONJUNTO FEEDER IBERIA (AG100AE2526E.) Y ENVIAR A RYMSA.
    
    
    ...
    VERIFICAR A-A</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0020</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>PREMONTAJE CONJUNTO BOCINA-POLARIZADOR
    ===========================================================================
    UNIR CONJUNTO BOCINA POS.01 CON POLARIZADOR POS.02 MEDIANTE TORNILLOS
    POS.08 Y ARANDELAS DE INVAR POS.10. S/SECCION E2-E2 DE</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0020</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>LA HOJA 01 DEL
    PLANO. COORDINAR CARAS INTERNAS DE POLARIZADOR CON EJES DE BOCINA SEGÚN
    NOTA 4.
    
    
    ...
    VERIFICAR A-A.
    
    ===========================================================================
    =    AVISAR A CONTROL DE PRODUCCION PARA ENVIAR</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0020</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>CONJUNTO A RF             =
    ===========================================================================</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0030</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>PRE-MONTAJE CONJUNTO BOCINA-SOPORTE BOCINA
    ===========================================================================
    MONTAR SOPORTE FEEDER IBERIA POS.03 EN CONJUNTO BOCINA IBERIA POS.01 CON
    TORNILLO POS.06 Y ARANDELA POS.07 S/SECCIÓN C1-C</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0030</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>1 Y E1-E1 DE LA HOJA 01 DEL
    PLANO.
    
    
    ...
    VERIFICAR A-A.
    
    ===========================================================================
    =        AVISAR A CONTROL DE PRODUCCIÓN PARA ENVIAR CONJUNTO A RF         =
    ===============================</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0030</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>============================================</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>MONTAJE FINAL CONJUNTO FEEDER - PORALIZADOR
    ===========================================================================
    MONTAR PASADORES POS.10 S/SECCIONES E1-E1 DE LAS HOJAS 01 DEL PLANO DESPUÉS
    DEL AJUSTE DE RF S/NOTA 01 DE LA HOJA 01 DEL</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>PLANO.
    
    PREPARAR MEZCLA DE ADHESIVO SOLITHANE S/IT-ERS-A005, APLICAR SOBRE ROSCA DE
    LOS TORNILLOS POS.08 Y DAR DE APRIETE DEFINITIVO 2NM+PAR DE FRENADO SEGÚN
    SECCIÓN TÍPICA DE LA HOJA 01 Y NOTAS 5 DEL PLANO.
    
    PREPARAR MEZCLA DE ADHESIVO EC</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>2216 S/IT-S-A043, SELLAR TORNILLOS
    POS.08 SEGÚN SECCIÓN TÍPICA Y NOTA  6 DE LA HOJA 01 DEL PLANO.
    
    MONTAJE FINAL CONJUNTO FEEDER - SOPORTE FEEDER
    ===========================================================================
    DAR DE APRIETE DEF</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>INITIVO A LOS TORNILLOS POS.06 DE 2,5NM+PAR DE FRENADO
    SEGÚN NOTA DEL PLANO.
    
    
    ...
    VERIFICAR A-A.</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0050</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>CARACTERIZAR CONJUNTO FEEDER IBERIA
    ===========================================================================
    VERIFICAR INTERFACES. RELLENAR REGISTRO DE INSPECCIÓN.
    
    
    ...
    VERIFICAR A-A-X</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0060</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>PRE-MONTAJE FEEDER &amp; GUIA DE ONDA IBERIA
    ===========================================================================
    REALIZAR OPERACIONES DESCRITAS EN EL APARTADO 6.4 DEL LIBRO DE MONTAJE.
    
    
    PRE-MONTAJE FEEDER IBERIA
    =======================</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0060</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>====================================================
    REALIZAR OPERACIONES DESCRITAS EN EL APARTADO 6.8.2 DEL LIBRO DE MONTAJE.
    
    
    MONTAJE FEEDER FINAL IBERIA
    ===========================================================================
    REALIZA</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0060</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>R OPERACIONES DESCRITAS EN EL APARTADO 6.10.2 DEL LIBRO DE MONTAJE.
    
    
    ...
    VERIFICAR A-A.</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0070</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>ALINEAMIENTO FEEDER IBERIA
    ===========================================================================
    ENGLOBA EL ALINEAMIENTO DEL FEEDER IBERIA. OPERACIÓN 6.9.2 DEL LIBRO DE
    MONTAJE.
    
    
    ...
    VERIFICAR A-A-X</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0080</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>REALIZAR VERIFICACIÓN FINAL.
    
    ...
    VERIFICAR A-A-G-X</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0090</OPERATION>
            <BAAN_TEXT_VAL>ALMACENAR HASTA SU PRÓXIMO MONTAJE.</BAAN_TEXT_VAL>
        </item>
    </TEXT>
    <TEXT_ASSIGN>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0010</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0020</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0030</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0040</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0050</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0060</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0070</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0080</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
        <item>
            <OPERATION>0090</OPERATION>
            <FROM />
            <TO />
        </item>
    </TEXT_ASSIGN>
</BAPI>
```

Inside the TEXT_ASSIGN block I need to calculate the FROM and TO values per OPERATION.
The values need to be based on the content of the TEXT node and define the first and last position within that node per OPERATION.
Simple example is OPERATION 0020, which would need to return a FROM of 2 and a TO of 4.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `TEXT` refers to the result element then it might be necessary to store that in a variable first to be able to select values in it. It would help us understand the problem if you can cut down the sample data and then also show the result you want to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve it with a variable:

```
    <xsl:variable name="text">
    <TEXT>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="concat(OPERATION, '|', BAAN_TEXT_LINE_SEQ)">
        <item>
          <xsl:copy-of select="OPERATION" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="BAAN_TEXT_VAL" />
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </TEXT>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$text"/>
    <TEXT_ASSIGN>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="OPERATION">
        <item>
          <xsl:copy-of select="OPERATION" />
          <xsl:variable name="indices" select="index-of($text/TEXT/item/OPERATION, current-grouping-key())"/>
          <FROM>
            <xsl:value-of select="$indices[1]"/>
          </FROM>
          <TO>
            <xsl:value-of select="$indices[last()]"/>
          </TO>
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </TEXT_ASSIGN>
```